# Activity.onDestroy does not destroy my view

Tags: android

In part of my Activity's code, I am calling Activity.finish() to close my activity, and the application returns to the main OS "desktop" window.

However, if I click on my application icon again, onCreate does not seem to be called and my view remains the same as when finish was called.

Perhaps, I'm not understanding the lifecycle correctly, but I thought that destroy completely destroyed the activity, and the next time it was invoked it would call onCreate.

Where am I misunderstanding this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In part of my Activity's code, I am calling Activity.finish() to close
>   my activity, and the application returns to the main OS "desktop"
>   window.
>
> However, if I click on my application icon again, onCreate does not
>   seem to be called (...)

Yes, it is called. Just `Log.d` and you'll see.

> and my view remains the same as when finish was
>   called.

It may remain the same because the XML content and all views instantiated are again created. However, if you modify stuff and layouts in code you'd see that it is restored to the defaults as in `setContentView(int layout)`.

> Perhaps, I'm not understanding the lifecycle correctly, but I thought that destroy completely destroyed the activity, and the next time it was invoked it would call onCreate.

As I said, it calls.

Comment: Also, please take a moment to see that finish(), *if I recall correctly*, will call `onDestroy()` without ever going into `onPause()` and `onStop()` before.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, onCreate is called (I had my logging level for this method set to verbose instead of debug). However, my view still remains in the same state. When the Activity is re-created after the instance variables initialized again? I'm using RoboGuice for dependency injection so perhaps some objects are not instantiated again...

Comment: Yes, I'd guess it's RoboGuice with its custom Inject mechanism. Try asking a question saying exactly that, or perhaps you should contact the RoboGuice team/forums... I don't see much people asking about it here, so I wonder if you'd ever get enough expertise. Anyway, just a suggestion.